# Modify attribute type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I modify the type (or domain) of a column (or attribute) in MySQL using `alter table` command?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alter table  .. could you must delete the data in some case (you can copy and the update)

```
 alter table your_table modify your_column  your_data_type;
```